# Generating Random number of 2^30

Tags: java, c++, c

I want to generate `2^30` random numbers in the range of 0 to 2^10. I heard that `rand()` function is not suitable for this many numbers.Is there any another way to generate it with nearly equal distribution?

Comment: Look into C++11's `<random>` header.

Comment: And in C++03, Boost.Random (where `<random>` came from).

Comment: Isn't there an issue with generating large random numbers with uniform distribution?

Comment: Seriously? `java`, `c++`, and `c`? Is your question related to all of these?

Comment: actually any language is suitable for me,I just want to redirect it to file!! If C/C++ then Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> g_random_int() return a random guint32 equally distributed over the range [0..2^32-1].

```
#include <glib.h>

int
main(void)
{
     g_print("%d\n", g_random_int());
   return 0;
}
```

with gcc:

```
gcc -o rand rand.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0`
```

EDIT:

reading directly from /dev/random (less portable), compile as usual:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int             fd;
    unsigned int    number;

    fd = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY);

    read(fd, &number, sizeof(number));

    printf("%u\n", number);
    close(fd);
  return 0;
}
```

PS: check for errors.

Comment: rand.c is my file where I stored this code?(sorry I have very less knowledge about complier)

Comment: @jhon
if you just want random numbers between 0 and 2^32 then just read from /dev/random it will give you randomness itself :P try this in your shell:

`od -An -N4 -tu /dev/random | tr -d ' '`
redirect to a file
`od -An -N4 -tu /dev/random | tr -d ' ' > file.txt`

but yes; if you copy and paste the code above into a file called rand.c you could actually compile it by just entering the command above. note that the code has a requirement, you need glib installed in your system.

Of course none of this will work if you are not using Linux.

Comment: ok thanks with the shell command I am able to do.But when I did it for file rand.c with above command it stuck up with symbol >>.

Comment: Oh well ... I hope then the shell command suits your needs. If not you can always make another question about how to compile the code, pretty easy tho. But I really recommend you use the command instead of someone else C/C++/Java code, just because /dev/random produces real random numbers.

Comment: ok now to call above script in C I am using system("/path/myscript.sh").It is giving output as expected but how to redirect it in variable.E.g:int abc=system("/path/myscirpt.sh")??

Comment: @john if you want to retrieve data from `myscript.sh` then you'll need to use environment variables, but thats a very ugly approach, instead, read directly from the device /dev/random. I updated the answer and added a sample code for you to try, happy coding mate ;)

Answer (score 3):

The C++ `<random>` library is an excellent option, with many choices of PRNG engine and distribution.

```
#include <random>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::random_device r;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
    std::mt19937_64 eng(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(0, 1<<10);

    for (std::uint32_t i = 0; i< (1<<30); ++i) {
        int value = dist(eng);
        std::cout << value << ' ';
    }
}
```

Also, random_device is itself an engine which may, depending on the implementation, provide access to a non-deterministic or cryptographic RNG:

```
std::random_device eng;
std::cout << dist(eng) << '\n';
```

For example in libc++ it uses /dev/urandom by default, which on OS X uses the Yarrow cryptographic RNG algorithm.

Comment: What compiler/library and versions are you using? It may not have implemented that yet. You could also try `std::mt19937` or one of the other [predefined random number generators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: @john you have to add the `-std=c++0x` compiler option

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can use Random which does repeat after 2^48 values.

```
Random rand = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < (1<<30); i++) {
    int n = rand.nextInt(1 << 10);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an old Usenet post with a number of interesting RNGs - all very easily implemented.

[http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/marsaglia-rng.html](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Eoz/marsaglia-rng.html)

They may not quite match the Mersenne twister, but I have made good use of several of them and they are certainly superior to some of the default rand() implementations.  They pass the DIEHARD tests of randomness and the largest period generator included has period > 2^7700 and takes no more than a couple of lines to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Mark A. Overton had a nice article on fairly simple but high quality RNGs on [Dr. Dobbs](http://drdobbs.com/tools/229625477) on May 24, 2011

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to increment the randomness and period:

```
public class Random2 {

    private static int LEN = 64;
    private final int[] buf = new int[LEN];
    private Random r;
    private final int maxInt = 1 << 10;

    public Random2() {
        r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
            buf[i] = r.nextInt(maxInt);
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        int i = r.nextInt(LEN);
        int x = buf[i];
        buf[i] = r.nextInt(maxInt);
        return x;
    }

}
```